# Map Editor Performance Advice

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, sfml

First of all don't think I'm making a "SFML and/or C++ performance Issue" type question. I'm not satisfied with the performance of this map editor I've been working on and I'm 99% percent sure I'm at fault for it.

Currently how I place tiles on the map is basically I have a function that loops through every single tile on the map and checks if the mouse is hovering over it. I call this function inside another function simply titled `handleMouseClick()`

This is plenty functional if you were just clicking each time you wanted to place a tile, however I have it sort of like a paintbrush. Even if there's only 500 tiles on the map, it will skip tiles if you drag it across the screen quickly. I need to be able to create maps that have 5000+ tiles and I can't afford so-so performance.

I've looked over my code and made sure I'm not making unnecessary copies. I'm pretty sure that the best way to increase performance would be to change how I check which tile the mouse is changing.

The only idea I have is to have the map in "chunks" so that it will check the tiles of the "chunk" the mouse is in.

Comment: Are your tiles square and all of the same size?

Comment: Yes, they are, your answer looks like it will definitely help thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use math.  Lets say you have tiles with pixel dimensions `{tile.width, tile.height}`.  And your application's window is a view of the map, and the top left corner of the window is on pixel `{view.x, view.y}`.  And the mouse position, relative to the top left corner of the window is `{mouse.x, mouse.y}`.  You can calculate which tile the mouse is pointing to with the following:

```
transformed_mouse.x = mouse.x + view.x;
transformed_mouse.y = mouse.y + view.y;

mouse_tile.x = transformed_mouse.x / tile.width;
mouse_tile.y = transformed_mouse.y / tile.height;
```

For handling a dragging effect where the event system doesn't update fast enough, keep track of where the mouse was for the previous iteration, and use [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to fill in all the tiles between the tile which the mouse is currently pointing to, and the tile which the mouse was pointing to previously.